# Why is my TListBox getting blank when its last TListBoxItem is checked?

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, tlistbox

### Problem

My `TListBox` is *getting blank* when its last `TListBoxItem` is *programatically* checked. To illustrate it better, hereby what I mean by *getting blank*:

[image]

---

### Context

I'm generating a list from a `TJSONArray`. Each item looks like `{"event_code","event_name"}`.

Then, I compare if the event_code is written on a second `TJSONArray` : `json_response_available_events`. If it does, the `ListBoxItem` will be checked.

---

### Code

```
procedure TFormHome.TimerGetEventsTimer(Sender: TObject);
var

    K                  : Integer;
    Z                  : Integer;
    ListCount          : Integer;
    AvailableList_Count: Integer;

    lb_item: TListBoxItem;

    event_code_first_array: string;
    event_code  : string;
    event_name  : string;

begin

    // Disable this timer for now
    TimerGetEvents.Enabled := false;

    // Get List of Notifications
    json_response_events           := DM_Auth0.ServerMethods1Client.GetEventsCodeAndDescription(communication_token);
    json_response_available_events := DM_Auth0.ServerMethods1Client.GetAllowedNotificationsList(communication_token, genset_id);

    ListCount                      := json_response_events.Count -1;
    AvailableList_Count            := json_response_available_events.Count - 1;

        for K := 0 to (ListCount) do
        begin

            // Get complete Event Code and Name
            event_name := json_response_events.Items[K].toString;

            // Get Event Code
            event_code_first_array := StringReplace(event_name.Split([':'])[0], '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

            // Get Event Name
            event_name   := StringReplace(event_name.Split([':'])[1], '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

            // Create ListBoxItem
            lb_item                := TListBoxItem.Create(self);
            lb_item.Parent         := lb_notifications;
            lb_item.Text           := event_name;
            lb_item.StyleLookup    := 'listboxitemleftdetail';

            // Check if this Item code is available
            for Z := 0 to (AvailableList_Count) do
            begin

                if json_response_available_events.Items[Z] <> nil then
                begin

                    // Get Event Code
                    event_code := json_response_available_events.Items[Z].toString;
                    // Format
                    event_code := StringReplace(event_code, '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

                    if event_code_first_array.Contains(event_code) then
                    begin

                        if K <= ListCount then
                        begin
                            lb_item.IsChecked  := true;
                            lb_item.IsSelected := false;
                        end;

                    end;

                end;

            end;

        end;

end;
```

---

### Analysis

If we set to `<` only, it displays the list correctly but the last item will remain unchecked.

```
if K < ListCount then
 begin
 lb_item.IsChecked  := true;
 lb_item.IsSelected := false;
end;
```

I can even change it's properties when its `=` like

```
if K = ListCount then
 begin
 lb_item.Text := 'Deadpool for President';
end;
```

and `lb_item.isChecked := false` works fine, but when setting `lb_item.isChecked := true` it gets all weirdly blank.

Why is it happening? And if there's a better way to do what I'm doing, the help will be appreciated.